# Can mangled concrete floor be fixed?

Tags: concrete, floor, garage

On our property there is a fairly old garage that hasn't been tended to in some time.  The floor is cracked and buckling.  What are possible fixes for this?

I've attached a photo.  If you look closely you can see that it has heaved up sharply through the patches.[image]

Comment: *Let Godzilla out of the basement. He knows that Mothra is coming to destroy you, and he only want to help!*  More seriously, that amount of movement indicates a problem below (*possibly not* radioactive movie monster related) and the fix is unlikely to be easy or cheap, and will probably involve removing the damaged concrete to resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm actually not willing to rule out Mothra at this point.  My assumption has always been that there isn't an easy fix, but this is well out of my wheelhouse and I am hoping someone has a clever idea.

Comment: If you are in a freeze-thaw zone this could be responsible for your problem. Garages are usually concrete poured slab-on-grade and the footings are only required to be 12" deep. That said, I would call a reputable concrete contractor for input. They may have an economical fix for you.

Comment: If it's well out of your wheelhouse, the clever idea *is* to call in a professional.

Comment: Buckling could be tree roots. Is there a tree fairly close to the garage? The only easy way for a home owner to decide....break out a chunk and see whats under it. Compact the ground and add gravel and sand to level it, compact it some more. Then clean out the crack with a dickie (concrete saw) and widen it a bit. Once you have prepped it all, get a load of concrete delivered, or start mixing bags and filling the holes in.

Comment: @ArchonOSX - I will be calling a contractor.  I'm just trying to get a feel for what I'm dealing with before I do so.

Comment: @mmathis - Just trying to get a handle on what to expect is all.

Comment: @JeffCates - Thanks for the info.  I imagine that's the fix, though I don't think it's due to a tree.  There's nothing nearby unless it's a really interesting root path.  I imagine it's a freeze/thaw issue, but the fix is likely the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Grind concrete until it is flat, then grout the remaining cracks.  You'll have an even thinner but flat floor, problem will likely re-occur.

or

b) Pour thicker new concrete over the top, with steel mesh, to make a more resilient replacement floor.  Might still crack, as base is suspect.

or

c) Cut out & remove the failed floor, inspect the base to determine true cause, remove failed layers, install proper bedding, insulation layer & damp proof membrane, re-pour concrete.